# How to apply lock or password on specific number's message

Tags: android

I have made an application in which I am fetching all the sms from inbox. The messages
are coming properly. I want to apply lock or password on particular number's 
message in my inbox so that the person who will access the inbox,won't be able to 
open the lock or password message. How can I apply lock or password on particular message ?